# Proving $\dim A = \dim A\otimes_k K$ by reducing to an irreducible component.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an equidimensional $k$-algebra with $\dim A = n$. Let $K/k$ be an algebraic extension. I just finished a proof that $A\otimes_k K$ is equidimensional with $\dim A\otimes_k K = n$ as well, but I am not comfortable with the first step I made, which was to reduce to the case $A$ is an integral domain.

I noted that since $A$ is equidimensional, we can mod out by any minimal prime $\mathfrak q$ and then we will have $\dim A = \dim A/\mathfrak q$, and $\dim A\otimes_k K=\dim A/\mathfrak q\otimes_k K$. The first equality is obvious, but the second I only made hand-wavingly so. How do I justify it more rigorously?

Comment: Why do you assume that $A$ is equidimensional? This is not needed. Or do you want to show that also $A \otimes_k K$ is equidimensional?

Comment: Yes. Because I was not asking for a whole proof here, but rather whether my reduction was correct, I didn't bother to mention that I wanted $A\otimes_k K$ to be equidimensional as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faster proof: By Noether normalization, $A$ is finite over some $k[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$. Hence, $A \otimes_k K$ is finite over $K[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$. qed.

Comment: That's nice proof, that is good to know of! However, I still want to know if I am allowed or not to make the reduction to the case $A$ is a domain the way I did.

Comment: There is no a priori reason why $A_K$ and $(A/q)_K$ have the same dimension. But a posteriori, we have $\dim((A/q)_K) \leq \dim(A_K) = \dim(A) = \dim(A/q) = \dim((A/q)_K)$.

Comment: Do you know how I could reduce to the case $A$ is a domain then?

Comment: My proof shows that every irreducible component of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ can at most split into irreducible components of the same dimension in $A_K$. This is almost shouting at me saying that it is obvious then that if $\operatorname{Spec} A$ has more than one irreducible component, but is equidimensional, they will all behave (split or not into irreducible components of same dimension) as if they were irreducible components alone. However, I was not able to prove this elementary fact.

Comment: If $\operatorname{Spec} A$ has finitely many irreducible components, then we can look at an affine opens $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ containing exactly each one of them. Then we use the bijection between irreducible closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ meeting $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ and irreducible closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ to isolate the splitting behavior of each irreducible component of $\operatorname{Spec} A$. But what if $\operatorname{Spec} A$ has infinitely many components?

Comment: By a directed colimit argument you may assume that $A$ is of finite type over $k$ (which is actually what I also assumed in my answer). Noetherian spaces have only finitely many irreducible components.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, such a trivial fact needs a very roundabout proof. First assume A is a domain, than that it is only of finite type, and then in general!

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand these are standard reduction techniques. One gets used to them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved this exercise without using this directed colimit argument to reduce to the finite type case. I'll leave it here in case anyone is interested.

Let $p: X_K \to X$ be the projection. We know the map $\mathrm{Spec} K \to \mathrm{Spec} k$ is integral, surjective, and flat, hence the same for $p$. This immediately tells us that $\dim(X) = \dim(X_K)$. The hard part is showing pure dimension. Suppose $X = \mathrm{Spec} A$ is pure dimension $n$. Then any irreducible component is o.t.f. $\mathrm{Spec} (A/\mathfrak{p})$ with $\mathfrak{p}$ a minimal prime of $A$. If $E \subset X_K$ is an irreducible component, we know $p(E) \subseteq X$ is irreducible ([Tag 0379](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0379)), closed (exercise 7.3.M, because $p$ is integral), and contained in some irreducible component $F$ of $X$.

Let's look at Vakil's hint for part (a). He suggests we look at an arbitrary irreducible component of $X$, say $F = \mathrm{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p})$ for $\mathfrak{p}$ a minimal prime. Then if $E \subset X_K$ is an irreducible component mapping into $F$ (all components are of this form for some $E$ so this is OK), it corresponds to a morphism of rings $A \to A' \to A'/\mathfrak{q}$ factoring through $A/\mathfrak{p}$, where $A' = A \otimes_k K$, $\mathfrak{q} \vartriangleleft A'$ is minimal, and $\mathfrak{p} \vartriangleleft A$ is minimal. If we just consider the map $A/\mathfrak{p} \to A'/\mathfrak{q}$, this is integral as quotients are integral and by exercise 7.2.B(a) in Vakil. One can show this map is injective and use exercise 11.1.E to conclude that $\dim(A'/\mathfrak{q}) = \dim(A/\mathfrak{p}) = n$, hence $X_K$ is pure dimension $n$. It might be interesting to note that injectivity of the above map is the same as saying $E$ surjects onto $F$ under $p$.